# ajaxComplete Not Working for my SlideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Been working on this site...

http://redrhinorestoration.com/wp/

But when you click on Services and then try to click on Show Services to slide up services it doesnt work. I posted here and got some help to use ajaxComplete so tried to do it but still didn't initiate the code for it to slide up but if you go to the Services page directly by typing it into the URL the slideup works but for some reason my close button on the slideup doesnt work.

Here is my ajaxComplete code maybe someone can shed some light to enlighten me more how to make it work correctly. I'm also having issue on the Process page my slider isnt showing up only if you go to that page directly.

```
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  showBottom.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuBottom, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showBottom' );
            };

});
```

Its become more of a headache then anythingusing the page transitions didn't think I would run into these type of issues lol.

Thanks for taking time to read my post and help out.

Comment: I think you need to make sure the page loads before you give a value to 'var showBottom'.. because it's null when add the onclick event to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with showBottom doesn't exist when you load the initial page. This breaks your code

```
showBottom = document.getElementById( 'showBottom' ) // showBottom will be null
```

This results in a few exceptions in your code. To avoid this, you could instead of doing this `showBottom.onclick = function() {` using [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like so

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#showBottom', function() { /* code here */ });
```

You are also trying to access jQuery with the $ variable (`$( ".services-tagger .ui-link" )`), which is undefined. To fix this, you can wrap your jQuery code in a wrapper

```
(function($){
    /* code using $ here */   
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks John,

I've done this but still is not working, I must have done something incorrectly somewhere, any chance you can take a peak to see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#element').live('click',function(){
  //code
  });
```

istead of your `showBottom.onclick`